# c++ AMP Concurrency::runtime_exception occurs when creating array_view

Tags: c++, c++-amp

I wanted to perform maxPool with C++ AMP. However, whenever I execute the code I face unexpected runtime exception and program just gets terminated.

Here is part of the code :

PoolLayer.h :

```
class PoolLayer : public Layer {
private:
    const int outpR, outpC, pR, pC, inpR, inpC, depth;
    std::vector<int> r_coordinate, c_coordinate;
    Tensor forwardPassGPU(const Tensor& input) override;
}
```

PoolLayer.cpp:

```
Tensor PoolLayer::maxPoolGPU(const Tensor& input, int depth) {
    Tensor ret(depth, outpR, outpC);
    array_view<double, 3> aret(depth, outpR, outpC, ret.list); // exception occurs
    array_view<const double, 3> ainput(depth, inpR, inpC, input.list); // exception doesn't occur
    array_view<int, 3> ar_coord(depth, outpR, outpC, r_coordinate); // exception occurs
    array_view<int, 3> ac_coord(depth, outpR, outpC, c_coordinate); // exception occurs
    
    // ... do maxpool
    }
```

Tensor is a class that I created, which has vector type variable "list". When I execute this code I get the error like : Microsoft C++ exception: Concurrency::runtime_exception, memory location 0x00D3F5A0. Currently I am using Visual Studio 2019, std:c++17 compiler. Also, I added /Zc:noexceptTypes- in command line to avoid any dynamic exception issues. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: PoolLayer.h also has maxPool function, Tensor maxPoolGPU(const Tensor& input, int depth).

Comment: [MCVE] needed.  This does not mean copy/pasting all of the code, it means reducing your code piece by piece, checking each step if the exception still occurs, until it is minimal and the exception still occurs.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  Thank you! I found what causes error. Error occured because outpR, outpC value was 0.

Comment: Making a mcve does that more than half the time.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred because oupR, outpC value was 0. Sorry for asking bad question.